# Firebase "message": "PASSWORD_LOGIN_DISABLED" response when trying to authenticate

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm following exactly the steps mentioned here:

https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/README.md

But I get the following error:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "PASSWORD_LOGIN_DISABLED"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "PASSWORD_LOGIN_DISABLED"
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you enable Email/Password authentication in your Firebase Console under Auth > Sign-In Method?

Comment: It is not silly, as long as it helps somebody that was completely lost because is new in this!

Answer (score 5):

Firebase has different Authentication methods inside the console such as email, Google, Facebook, Twitter, and more.

Therefore make sure that you have (in this case) the Email/Password sign in method activated:

1. Go to the console.
2. Click on the Authentication Menu on the sidebar.
3. Inside Sign-In Method make sure to have the "Email/Password" option.

Also, make sure you already have the user created on the Users tab.

On the other hand, you can create the user with the same Pyrebase library.

```
auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
```

Check out the [Example Code](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#creating-users) inside the API.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this error by copying the `firebaseConfig` from **PROJECT** settings and pasted again. Make sure you have enable **Email/Password** in Sign-in Methods

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, I didn't pay close enough attention to the Firebase docs on when to switch tenantId, and I was confused when I got the PASSWORD_LOGIN_DISABLED error after adding a tenant.  So, I modified my `firebaseAuth.ts` file to automatically switch.

Curiously, the Email/Password and Google providers play nice and don't need separate tenants.  The Microsoft provider gave me the `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` error and I didn't want to bother my users with linking accounts.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { OAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  tenantId_MicrosoftAuth: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_TENANT_ID_MICROSOFT_AUTH,
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

const firebaseAuth_EmailPassword = () => { firebaseAuth.tenantId = null; return firebaseAuth; };

const firebaseAuth_Google = () => { firebaseAuth.tenantId = null; return firebaseAuth; };
const firebaseAuthProvider_Google = new GoogleAuthProvider();

const firebaseAuth_Microsoft = () => { firebaseAuth.tenantId = firebaseConfig.tenantId_MicrosoftAuth || null; return firebaseAuth; };
const firebaseAuthProvider_Microsoft = new OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');

export {
  firebaseAuth_EmailPassword,
  firebaseAuth_Google,
  firebaseAuth_Microsoft,
  firebaseAuthProvider_Google,
  firebaseAuthProvider_Microsoft,
}
```